# Why is my palm tree not coming back to life?

Tags: diagnosis, watering

It's been yellow like this since the winter and no amount of water can make it green. What's the problem here?[image]

Comment: What I find interesting is that your ground cover is pretty sensitive to cold but not as much as your palm.  And it is doing quite well, needs watering. Japanese pachysandra.  What kind of palm was this, do you know?  Date palms are very susceptible to cold, I had my clients who insisted on these plants wrap them in burlap and christmas tree lights and they were able to (zone 5) keep them healthy and alive.  Pachysandra isn't as tender but still...how many winters did this palm survive? Where is it you live, what zone?  Pull those dandelions while they aren't making seed by the way, grins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry to say that your palm is 100% completely dead. Once that centermost frond turns completely brown, the growing potential is lost and there's no bringing it back. The entire plant will have to be removed.

My guess is it simply did not survive the winter months. It is  difficult to tell from your photo, but it appears to be a Robellini or Pygmy Date Palm — whose cold hardiness is rated down to USDA Zone 9a (20 °F, -6.6 °C).

Comment: victorville does get that cold

Answer (score 6):

Has the frost killed it off? If the centre part was frozen, then it's probably dead.

Have a look at this YouTube video:

[Freeze Damage Part 3-Palms (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/81fxNatT2lQ)

It may possibly still be alive, but if after a few months you don't get any growth it'll be dead. I've got one and it grows so slowly that I thought it was dead before. By the photo it looks like yours is dead, but it depends if the middle part where the leaves come from is dead or not.

Comment: so it has to be taken out and replaced?

Comment: Hi! I added the information in your comments to your answer. Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to add extra information to it. Thanks, and welcome to the site!